# Was Mass Effects’s Blue Suns a nod to Firefly?

Tags: firefly, mass-effect

I was reading [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/what-is-blue-sun-in-firefly), and it got me wondering...

Were any of the Mass Effect production team involved with making, or intense fans of, Firefly — thus suggesting that Mass Effects’s Blue Suns organisation was a tribute or nod to Firefly’s Blue Sun Corporation?

Obviously, any answer here would be out-of-universe.

Comment: I think an answer to this needs to have some documentary evidence really - from a writer or producer on the show.  However the mass-effect wiki does say that this link is 'likely'

Comment: Maybe in Mass Effect 3 the Blue Suns will have a ship called the Firefly.

Comment: Hmmm, why not? The Firefly class already made an appearance in `Battlestar Galactica (RDM)`.

Comment: One of the writers for ME3 is John Dombrow. He also wrote a movie called "Control Factor" which was released in 2003 starring Adam Baldwin.  Adam Baldwin appears in both the ME series and "Firefly." Maybe that's the connection?

Comment: Oh cool; I didn't realize he had worked on ME. Great little piece of trivia!

Comment: Oddly, in SQL `Mass Effect <> Firefly` implies `Mass Effect != Firefly`

Comment: True, and I'm a programmer too, so I'm not sure why my mind wrote it that way... `Mass Effect <--> Firefly` would've been more indicative of what I meant. lol

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, an introduction of the two groups in question:

### Blue Suns (Mass Effect)

> The Blue Suns are a "private security organization", in reality a mercenary outfit operating in the Skyllian Verge.

They start out and continue as a mercenary group. Their logo is something like:

[image: Blue sun form mass effect]

### Blue Sun Corporation (Firefly)

The blue sun corporation in Firefly a large corporate company, selling food and technology. Its logo is seen across the series:

[image: Bluesun firefly]

However various operatives are seen in the series that shows the darker side to the company, who seem to be after River (and River seems to even be spooked by their image). They are however not a mercenary group being called out to whoever pays.

As to links between the two, there are a few:

From the Degrees of Whedon tumblr:

> 1. Seth Green voices Jeff “Joker” Moreau in ME3. Seth Green was Oz in Joss Whedon’s Buffy the Vampire Slayer.
>
> Mass Effect 3 has 1 degree of Whedon.

Even more there are *other references* to Firefly:

> Zaeed at one point calls you "big ***damn heroes," which is a less-censored version of one of the most popular quotes from the show.
>   And
>
> One of joker's quotes if you just stand around him without talking: "Sometimes I just want to disable the internal compensators and pull a Crazy Ivan"

As well as this I ran both cast lists (combined Mass effect 1,2,3 and Firefly) through some bash script filters and I can't find any duplicates besides Adam Baldwin.

I'd say the link was tenuous at best, no more influence here than you might imagine from anything else that's inspired the show (and there are a lot of shout outs, especially in ME2.)

The one thing I did find that might be a link or inspiration is [Black Suns](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Sun) a mercenary group from Star Wars.

Comment: So about as much influence as one might expect between any two programs in the sci-fi/acting community, but probably nothing direct.

Comment: Yeah, petty much. I doubt anyone from the crew or staff leisure actively thought to imitate the Bluesun corporation.

Comment: The idea of a "Crazy Ivan" is at least as old as *The Hunt for Red October*, so it's possible ME3 and Firefly both independently referenced it.  The ME3 writers were certainly *aware* of *Red October* since they also threw in a more overt reference to it (something about "singing the Russian national anthem" while the stealth drive was on).